# número perfecto en python

Tags: python

estoy haciendo este código en un programa, del cual no sale la impresión, entonces me gustaría saber qué está mal, como para qué no se imprima la información, gracias.

```
ent=int(input())
for i in range(2, ent):
    b=0
    for j in range(1, (i//2)+1):
        if((i%j)==0):
            b= b+j;
    if(b==i):
        print("perfecto")
else:
    print("no perfecto")
```

Comment: ¿Podrias explicar que intentas hacer? Por el código parece que intentas, dado un numero `ent` , ver si cada numero  entre 2  y  `ent` (no incluido) es o no perfecto. En ese caso el único error es que debes añadir un nivel de identación al else.

Comment: Un *número perfecto* es aquel que es suma de sus divisores. En tu código, `i` nunca llega a valer `ent`, nunca compruebas si la suma de divisores llega a ser el número.

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en la formulación (el rango debe ser hasta `ent+1` segùn ChemaCortes) e indentación según FJSevilla. Y mostramos la variable `i` para tu `print`.

```
ent=int(input())
for i in range(2, ent+1):
    b=0
    for j in range(1, (i//2)+1):
        if((i%j)==0):
            b= b+j;
    if(b==i):
        print("%s es perfecto" %i)
    else:
        print("%s no es perfecto" %i)
```

## ENTRADA

```
30
```

## SALIDA

```
2 no es perfecto
3 no es perfecto
4 no es perfecto
5 no es perfecto
6 es perfecto
7 no es perfecto
8 no es perfecto
9 no es perfecto
10 no es perfecto
11 no es perfecto
12 no es perfecto
13 no es perfecto
14 no es perfecto
15 no es perfecto
16 no es perfecto
17 no es perfecto
18 no es perfecto
19 no es perfecto
20 no es perfecto
21 no es perfecto
22 no es perfecto
23 no es perfecto
24 no es perfecto
25 no es perfecto
26 no es perfecto
27 no es perfecto
28 es perfecto
29 no es perfecto
30 no es perfecto
```